# jQuery resizable on image

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a site to develop in CodeIgniter, and I want to upload an image with AJAX and make it resizable. I'm able to upload and show the image but it isn't resizable.

This is my upload script:

```
public function ajaximage(){
        $path = "uploads/tee/element/";
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
        if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];
        if(strlen($name))
        {
            list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
        {
        if($size<(1024*1024)) // Image size max 1 MB
        {
            $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
            $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
            {
                echo "<img src='".base_url().$path.$actual_image_name."' class='resizable' width='200px' height='100px'>";
            }
            else
                echo "failed";
            }
            else
                echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
            }
            else
                echo "Invalid file format..";
            }
            else
                echo "Please select image..!";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

This is my AJAX function that handles the request. I have to put the image inside a `div`, and the image must be resizable:

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".resizable").resizable();

        function showResponse(responseText){
            $(responseText).appendTo("#space-drawable-div").resizable();
            $(responseText).css('position','absolute').css('top','0px').css('left','0px').css('z-index','5');
        }

        $('#upload-form').ajaxForm(showResponse);

    });


    </script>
```

The image is shown, but I can't resize it.

There's no error shown in the console.

Comment: Execute the call to `resizable()` *after* the image has been appended.  You're doing it before the image exists in the DOM ;)

Comment: I have tried this:$(responseText).appendTo("#space-drawable-div");
            $(responseText).css('position','absolute').css('top','0px').css('left','0px').css('z-index','5').resizable();

but doesn't work! @Archer

Comment: Put the 1st line [`$(".resizable").resizable()`] as the last line in the function.